# Using Hough Transform to find lines, but also need to track the points found on these lines

Tags: c, opencv, hough-transform

This isn't really a 2D problem, but actually a simplification of a 3D problem.  So it's not a straight image analysis question.

I have a set of 2D points that I will use to render a 3D surface map.  I could draw all of the points as vertices but this is wasteful as many of these points will form lines and other simple shapes that can be rendered much more easily.  I can use the Hough Transform with OpenCV to find these lines; however the OpenCV function doesn't tell me what points in my set would lie on these lines.

I need to know either the subset of points that **don't** lie on lines found in the Hough Transform, so I know to render them as vertices, or those that **do* so I know not to render them.

In other words, it doesn't do any good to find simplified shapes if I can't somehow exclude the vertices I don't need to draw anymore.

Another detail: The application is constantly adding new points that may or may not need to be rendered.  I figure I can re-run the Hough Transform on the full set of points as needed (once per rendering frame) but again this is inefficient since the image won't necessarily change that much.  Is there another way to approach the problem?

Comment: if you use the PPHT instead of the standard Hough line transform, instead of infinite lines you'd be returned the end-points of line segments. then its a simple matter of checking which of your points would (1) satisfy the equation of the hough line and (2) if they are falling in between the two end-points.

Answer (score 0):

The Hough transform gives you equations of lines (ie infinitely long lines not segments).

Once you have these equations you could test how [far each point is from a line](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointline/) and decide whether it is on the line or not (given some maximum distance).

When you add new points you can do the same test to see if they are sufficiently close to any of the existing lines.

Comment: wouldn't using the probabilistic hough transform give line segments? http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/feature_detection.html#houghlines2